# Find nearest prior row with specific condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have the following table:

| id | column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | value A |
| 2 | value B |
| 3 | value D |
| 4 | value C |
| 5 | value D |
| 6 | value D |
| 7 | value D |
| 8 | value E |
| 9 | value F |
| 10 | value D |

For each row with value D, I need to find the nearest above row with a value different than D. So what I need is:

| id | nearest row id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | null |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 8 | null |
| 9 | null |
| 10 | 9 |

How can  I achieve this in PostreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally this should be done via `LAG() IGNORE NULLS (...)` but PostgreSQL does not support it. The workaround is to think that every value other than `value d` starts a group, then copy the desired value across the group:

```
with cte1 as (
    select *, case when b = 'value d' then null else id end as grp_id
    from t
), cte2 as (
    select *, sum(case when grp_id is not null then 1 end) over (order by id) as grp_num
    from cte1
)
select *, case when b = 'value d' then max(grp_id) over (partition by grp_num) end as nearest_row_id
from cte2
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=10bdfbf5a893638155b41473b7dc555b)